replace php templating variables between double curly braces that are nested inside two-character code delimiters
I am working on a custom minimalist PHP templating engine for use in personal projects,  I need to solve how to make some replacements using a regular expression. I have this string:
$string = 'sometext {% {{ var1 }} middletext {{ var2 }} %} moretext {{ varx }} {% {{ var3 }} %}';

I want to replace all variables between {{ }} delimiters with their php equivalent, but only if they are nested inside  {% %} delimiters
This is the desired output:
sometext {% $var1 middletext $var2 %} moretext {{ varx }} {% $var3 %}

So far I have tried this:
echo preg_replace('#\{\{\s*(.*?)\s*\}\}#', '\$$1', $string);

I have even tried this Regex with lookaheads:
echo preg_replace('#(?=.*\{%?)\{\{\s*(.*?)\s*\}\}(?=.*%\})(?!=.*\{%.*%\})#', '\$$1', $string);

But, in both cases I get the same output: All variables in the string are replaced irrespective of being inside {% %} delimiters or not (note how $varx is also undesirably replaced), my incorrect output is:
sometext {% $var1 middletext $var2 %} moretext $varx {% $var3 %}

I have solved it and gotten the output I desire by using foreach loops to match {% %} delimiters first and then replace the variables in the string by using arrays in preg_replace(), like this:
<?php
$string = 'sometext {% {{ var1 }} middletext {{ var2 }} %} moretext {{ varx }} {% {{ var3 }} %}';
$phpcode = preg_match_all('#{%.*?%}#', $string, $matches);
if ($phpcode) {
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        if (is_array($match)) {
            foreach ($match as $value) {
                $replacements[] = preg_replace('/{{\s*(.*?)\s*}}/', '\$$1', $value);
                $patterns[] = "/" . preg_replace('/([\[\]\{\}\.\*\+\$\/\?\^])/', '\\\$1', $value) . "/";
            }
        }
    }
}
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);

the output can be tested here
But ...  I'm pretty sure theres a simple one-line of preg_replace() regex code that can achieve the same desired output. Any ideas?

Use preg_replace_callback().

The regexp will be \{\{%.*?%\}\}, and the callback function can then replace the {.*?} patterns using the the template parameters.
